# Retrofit 2 Multipart requests

Tags: android, retrofit, kotlin

I'm migrating my existing codebase to Retrofit 2, but having some trouble understanding the new syntax for Multipart requests. I'm also using Kotlin, although apart from a few syntax changes I think it shouldn't matter for this particular question.

Here's what I have right now:

```
val audioDuration = RequestBody.create(null, audioDuration.toString())
val file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/mp4"), 
               File(context.filesDir, filename).absoluteFile)

sendAudioChunk(audioDuration, file).enqueue(callback)
```

And here's the definition of the API:

```
@Multipart
@POST("path_to_request")
fun sendAudioChunk(@Part("duration") audioDuration: RequestBody,
                   @Part("audio") audioBlob: RequestBody) : Call<ResponseObject>
```

On Retrofit 1.9 I used TypedString and TypedFile for the request parameters, and now it seems one need to use RequestBody from OkHttp but I must be missing something since the request does not execute correctly.

Comment: Jake Wharton's solution here is the recommended way of doing this;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507040/how-to-set-dynamic-filename
You create the @Part parameters with type MultipartBody.Part parameters which can include a filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. My web-service expects a filename for file uploads. This seems to be a work in progress support in the new Retrofit 2, but it is possible to circumvent the problem by adding it to the named parameter definition.

More details here : https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1140

Comment: it would be nice if you just showed an example of what to do here. This took me awhile of scouring these threads to find the correct solution which was not what many people advocate (embedding it in a RequestBody name parameter by escaping the quote)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that is different is that `TypedString` would have a `Content-Type` of "text/plain; charset=UTF-8", where you are not setting a `Context-Type` at all for your `audioDuration` parameter.  Try setting it to `text/plain` to get the same behavior as `TypedString` (charset will be set to utf-8 by default).

```
val audioDuration = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), audioDuration.toString())
```

If that doesn't work, you'll need to provide more information about how the "request does not execute correctly". A working request that you are trying to replicate would also be helpful.

Comment: Did that, and still doesn't work. I get a 200 but the server sees the message length as having no contents. On the previous version of retrofit the contents got there alright, and I'm doing everything else the same way (or at least I think so). The server is running on app engine, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Do you have a transcript of a working request from your old code?