# How to set dynamic filename?

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

Using retrofit 2, how would I set a dynamic name for the uploaded file?

Currently, it's like this:

```
@Part("avatar\"; filename=\"image\" ") RequestBody image,
```

However, the uploaded file name would be `image` without the extension.
Any recommendation on this case?

Answer (score 5):

Define your endpoint with `MultipartBody.Part` as the type:

```
interface Example {
  @Multipart //
  @POST("/foo/bar/") //
  Call<ResponseBody> method(@Part MultipartBody.Part part);
}
```

and then use its factories to create the type:

```
RequestBody body = // image body...
Call<ResponseBody> call = example.method(
    MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", "whatever.png", body));
```